# JUnit5 - is there any reliable way to get class of an executed test

Tags: java, junit5

I am writing a test execution listener. A little extension for Junit5 framework.  There is a necessity to know what class is used when running a particular test having `TestIdentifier` and `TestPlan`.

```
((MethodSource) id.getSource().get()).getClassName();
```

Gives only the class, where a test is **declared**.
But, that does not mean that it is run from declared class.

For instance a test can be run from a subclass.

Parsing results for `TestIdentifier#getUniqueId()`
Can differ from case to case 
(single test for junit4, single test for junit5, dynamic test for junit5 , parametrized test for junit4, etc)

At this moment I did not find any possibility to do that.

Is there any reliable way to get class of an executed test ?

Comment: [TestInfo](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInfo.html) used as a parameter like described at [3.9. Dependency Injection](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dependency-injection) could help. At least, there's an optional `getTestClass()` accessor.

Comment: Unfortunatelly that is not the case I consider. 
TestExecutionListener is not aware of what is passed as params to test methods.  

In addition it implies that every tests method has to have TestInfo as param - it is not always so

Comment: I might not have followed your requirement exactly. In JUnit4 (& I presume 5), we use a couple of `@Rule` annotations (one is a TestWatcher(), the other is just the TestName()) to get at part of your question. We have also used Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() and emitted the proper information from the stack trace.

Comment: TestExecutionListener  in JUnit5 is a kind of listener that gets events(notifications) of test start, test end, test skipped.    once connected to test execution framework it can listen to result of **any** tests - any test starts, finishes or can be skipped.  therefore Junit4 and Junit5 tests are also a possible part of this process. 
 Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()  is a good idea . but   TestExecutionListener notifications are not called from executed test method - as result class cannot be found in this stack trace. Test is invoked,  then notification is sent.

Answer (score 3):

Save a reference to [`TestPlan`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/TestPlan.html) in [`testPlanExecutionStarted`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener.html#testPlanExecutionStarted-org.junit.platform.launcher.TestPlan-) and inspect the `TestSource` of the `TestIdentifier`'s parent using `testPlan.getParent(testIdentifier)`. If it's a `ClassSource`, you can access the `Class` via `classSource.getJavaClass()`.

Comment: Suggested decision does not work for all cases, although some of them can be covered.  

For instance it does not work for JUnit5 dynamic tests - if dynamic test is being run 

testPlan.getParent(identifier).get().getSource() 

does not contain ClassSource

In case when Junit4 parametrized test is run 

testPlan.getParent(identifier).get().getSource()  for that parametrized test is null.

Answer (score 1):

I found temporary solution for described situation.
The idea is to go through all parents and find first that contains ClassSources, then use that ClassSource.

```
private static String findTestMethodClassName(TestPlan testPlan, TestIdentifier identifier) {
    identifier.getSource().orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
    identifier.getSource().ifPresent(source -> {
        if (!(source instanceof MethodSource)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("identifier must contain MethodSource");
        }
    });


    TestIdentifier current = identifier;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getSource().isPresent() && current.getSource().get() instanceof ClassSource) {
            return ((ClassSource) current.getSource().get()).getClassName();
        }
        current = testPlan.getParent(current).orElse(null);
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Class name not found");
}
```

Although that solution covers my needs it makes no guaranty that framework behaviour is not changed in future and cannot be considered reliable at this moment.

The issue is posted to https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/737